# PHP - How to get number from specific case as array

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

Here is my string:

```
$string = 'This the s number [:[123084]:] and [:[123085]:] 12374 [:[123087]:]';
```

How to get number if number is  to [:[xxxx]:]this case? I want to get number(xxxx) from this case as array.

I want the result something like this:

```
$array = array( 123084, 123085, 123087);
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: https://eval.in/911196

Comment: It output all number. doesn't output specific number from [:[xxxx]:]  this case....

Comment: Why the last number (ie. `123087`) is not selected?

Comment: because this is not my case... I want number only from this case: [:[123085]:] output: 123085

Comment: 123087 is not my case so this is not selected

Comment: Yes,  understand, but `123087` in within `[:[` and `]:]`

Comment: What are the rules? Why not all the numbers within `[:[` and `]:]`? I'll be happy to give you an answer if you give the rules.

Comment: I want to get number between  [:[number]:] .

Comment: Finally i got solution. thanks for trying to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the job:

```
$string = 'This the s number [:[123084]:] and [:[123085]:] 12374[:[123087]:]';
preg_match_all('/(?<=\[:\[)\d+(?=\]:\])/', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123084
            [1] => 123085
            [2] => 123087
        )
)
```

**Explanation:**

```
/           : regex delimiter
  (?<=      : lookbehind, zero length assertion, make sure we have the following BEFORE the current position
    \[:\[   : literally [:[
  )         : end lookbehind
  \d+       : 1 or more digits
  (?=       : lookahead, zero length assertion, make sure we have the following AFTER the current position
    \]:\]   : literally ]:]
  )         : end lookahead
/           : regex delimiter
```

You will find usefull informations [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)